# how to get a filter array from gqgrid

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm using this php code to generate a grid.

```
<?php

//ini_set("display_errors","1");
require_once 'grid/jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once "grid/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once "grid/jqGridArray.php";

// include the calendar
require_once "grid/jqCalendar.php"; 

// include the document class 
require_once "lib/document.php";
// include heler.php which contain some helper functions
require_once "lib/helper.php";
// create the array connection
$conn = new jqGridArray();
// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);


echo $_REQUEST["filters"];
```

I want when a user to search by a toolbar take the parameter search by the $_REQUEST variable and pass to my function and return the new result.

the result of `echo $_REQUEST["filters"];`

```
{\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"BatchNumber\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"56\"},{\"field\":\"SenderCode\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"string1\"},{\"field\":\"ReceiverCode\",\"op\":\"bw\",\"data\":\"string2\"}]}{"records":0,"page":0,"total":0,"rows":false}
```

I want the result to be like

```
$filter = array("BatchNumber" => 56 , 
"SenderCode" => "string1",
"ReceiverCode" => "string2"
 )
```

and there are also other fields that I want to search in them and display in array like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem you should change the value of `stringResult` property of  [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching) from `true` to `false`. The option `stringResult: true` make format of the information send to the server compatible to advanced searching. So the [filters](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aadvanced_searching#options) parameter will be sent to the server.